# How to force Scrollable Fragments that each take up the width of the screen to only show one at a time?

Tags: android

Hopefully what I am asking makes sense. Lets assume I want to use, say a HorizontalView, and add 3 Fragments to it. Normally it would scroll, but you could end up with half of two views showing. I want to force the Fragments to automatically fall into place to show only one. I would also not mind another implementation, which would be knowing how to tell how much of a Fragment is showing on the screen, as to give it the center stage so the speak. How can I accomplish this? Much appreciated. If any clarification is needed, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using `ViewPager` for this, since it already implements the feature you want?

Comment: Was hoping no one asked this lol! I do not wish to support anything before HoneyComb. Hence, using the compatibility library would provide little benefit. I do understand it would make what I am trying to accomplish easier, but bare with me here!

Answer (score 0):

> I do not wish to support anything before HoneyComb

So?

> Hence, using the compatibility library would provide little benefit.

The Android Support package has not been called "the compatibility library" in over a year. That is because the Android Support package is not merely for backports of newer capabilities. It also adds code for which Google wishes to supply us with a full implementation but does not want to bake into the firmware. `ViewPager` is the pre-eminent example of this.

Talented programmers, therefore, would add the Android Support package to their apps and implement your desired capability using `ViewPager`, recognizing that all the rest of the Android Support package will be removed by ProGuard as part of the production build.

Comment: @Andy: You are certainly welcome to read the source code to `ViewPager` -- downloaded as part of downloading the Android Support package -- and see how it does it.

Comment: Will do @CommonsWare If you don't mind. What other useful classes are in the support package that aren't for backwards compatibility purposes? Well in your expert opinion and experience.

Comment: @Andy: `NavUtils` is the other thing I see in the `android.support.*` packages that is native to the Android Support package.

Comment: So I have done more research, besides `ViewPager`, I honestly see absolutely no reason to use the support package. I also want to point this specific quote from the support page itself: `The goal is to simplify your development by offering more APIs that you can bundle with your application so you can worry less about platform versions.` Since I will not support anything pre-honeycomb, I stand by my original point since doing so would actually require more work lol. I appreciate your input though.